# how to write to a directory C

Tags: c

I'm trying to copy directory contents to another directory 
but I'm having a problem with writing to the second directory without using `sprintf`; Any suggestions?

```
void Copying(char *folder1, char *folder2) {
    DIR *s1, *s2;
    struct dirent *dep;

    if ((s1 = opendir(folder1)) == NULL) {
        printf("Error\n");
        return;
    }
    if ((s2 = opendir(folder2)) == NULL) {
        printf("Error \n");
        return;
    }

    while ((dep = readdir(s1)) != NULL) {
        //write(s2 , dep->d_name , sizeof(dep) ) ; // <- 
    }
    closedir(s1);
    closedir(s2);

    return;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you can *write* a `dirent` struct to a second open `DIR` to copy the contents? You have to re-create each directory in the new location and copy each file (using the `d_name` member of the `dirent` struct) to the new directory *location*, not open directory pointer. Suggest looking at `ftw` or `nftw` to automate walking the directory tree.

Comment: You can also *link* the files from the source directory - if the file system supports hardlinks. But then there is just one set of files that can be found in multiple directories.

Answer (score 1):

This approach won't work. Directory handles are not writable.

If you want to copy the contents of a directory, you will need to copy each file, directory, and link in the source directory individually. To copy each file, you will need to create a new file in the target directory and write the contents of the source file into it.